# JQuery bug on <section>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got an issue, breaking my head on it for a long time already .

Trying to select the `<input>`'s of that html :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var markup = $('section fieldset input').length;
  alert(markup);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="buttonDiv">
   <fieldset>
     <legend>General Information</legend>
     <input type="submit" class="submit" name="btnUser" value="Users Activity" id="btnUser" />
     <input type="submit" class="submit" name="btnLast50Activities" value="Last 50 Activities" id="btnLast50Activities" />
     <input type="submit" class="submit" name="btnCounts" value="Data Element Count" id="btnCounts" />
     <input type="submit" class="submit" name="btnSilConfigurations" value="SIL Configuration" id="btnSilConfigurations" />
     <input type="submit" class="submit" name="btnApiMsg" value="Listener Connections" id="btnApiMsg" />
     <input type="submit" class="submit" name="btnLisConn" value="Application IDs" id="btnLisConn" />
   </fieldset>
 </section>

 <section class="buttonDiv">
   <fieldset>
     <legend style="color: blue; font-weight: bold;">Settings</legend>
     <input type="submit" class="submit" name="SILApi" value="SIL MQ Settings" id="btnSilSettings" />
     <input type="submit" class="submit" name="ABatchRunner" value="Batch MQ Settings" id="btnBatchMqSettings" />
     <input type="submit" class="submit" name="btnEnvSettings" value="Environment Settings" id="btnEnvSettings" />
   </fieldset>
 </section>
```

So in Chrome, it returns 9 just as it should, but when running on Internet Explorer, although it's old, It returns 0 .
I don't understand why ! Explorer 9 suppose to support it .

P.S. - When removing from the jQuery selection the section ( `$('fieldset input')`) it returns a good result, but I want to know why the section messes it up.

AND - If i use `alert($('section').length` i Get 2 which is good , if i use 
`alert($('fieldset input').length` i get 9 which is good, but when using all three 
`alert($('section fieldset input').length` i get 0 .
Nonsence ! :-\ .

Comment: I just tried it on IE9 and it works fine. Are you sure you're not using anything lower than IE9?

Comment: [link]http://snag.gy/tcyZX.jpg Yeah i guess by your answer it must be some locally problem .. i just can't figure out what .. I'll try to work on it a bit more.. Thanks a lot !

Comment: http://snag.gy/ib5Y8.jpg

Comment: see my last edit comments, maybe it helps in anything ..

Comment: Have you declared your doctype correctly? As in `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the html?

Comment: Yeah .. I'll test it some more in order to understand why it happened .. the weird thing is that chrome get it right ..

Comment: No, the *weirdest* thing is that IE9 gets it *wrong*. Double-check the doctype, and make sure your markup is valid.

Comment: Click that broken page icon so it's not highlighted http://snag.gy/FJwO9.jpg

Comment: Ha, that worked Novocaine .. I just missed that,.. but I can't keep asking users to click that button. IE make it impossible to use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion to turn off IE9's 'compatibility mode', you can attempt to do this in the document by providing a `<meta>` tag (must be the first meta tag) within the `<head>`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>My Web Page</title>
</head>
```

Be sure, though, that your actual IE9 settings have not been set to force [compatibility view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2536204) to be on, through the Tools > Compatibility View settings.

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot .. Nobody really should use IE :), It's just some default browser in some of the users..

Answer (score 4):

IE 8 and lower need to have each new HTML5 element created (`document.createElement('section')`) before they understand what to do with them. There’s a project called [HTML5Shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) that’ll do this for you for all HTML5 elements if you include their supplied JS into your site:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="javascripts/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

(assuming you’ve uploaded it to your site in the javascripts directory).

Comment: Good point. I don’t know of any reason selection of `section` would fail in IE9. OP, can you elaborate?

Comment: My guess would be that the OP has been a little loose with his description. Just fired up a Virtual Machine with IE9 on it, tested the code and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in old version of IE that, it do all unrecognized tags as empty tags.

That mean IE, parse your DOM in as

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="buttonDiv" />
            <fieldset>
                <legend>General Information</legend>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="btnUser" value="Users Activity" id="btnUser" />
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="btnLast50Activities" value="Last 50 Activities" id="btnLast50Activities" />
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="btnCounts" value="Data Element Count" id="btnCounts" />
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="btnSilConfigurations" value="SIL Configuration" id="btnSilConfigurations" />
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="btnApiMsg" value="Listener Connections" id="btnApiMsg" />
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="btnLisConn" value="Application IDs" id="btnLisConn" />
            </fieldset>
<!--ignored            <section></section> -->

        <section class="buttonDiv" />
            <fieldset>
                <legend style="color: blue; font-weight: bold;">Settings</legend>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="SILApi" value="SIL MQ Settings" id="btnSilSettings" />
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="ABatchRunner" value="Batch MQ Settings" id="btnBatchMqSettings" />
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="btnEnvSettings" value="Environment Settings" id="btnEnvSettings" />
            </fieldset>
<!--ignored            <section></section> -->
```

To workaround with that bug.

You will need to do document.createElement("section") in `<head></head>` before DOM parse try to parse it first time.

Answer (score 1):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg593059(v=vs.85).aspx:

> The **section** element is only supported for webpages displayed in IE9
>   Standards mode.

To enable standards mode in IE9, make sure you have this line at the top of your file:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, good point. My HTML5Shiv answer will help with IE9 too in that case.